# coalesce in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a column called `Indicator` in a table. It contains `Y`, `N`, `NULL`, or just blank.

What does the following two logic do?

```
coalesce(Indicator, 'N') = 'N'
coalesce(Indicator, 'N') = 'Y'
```

It doesn't seem just to return the rows where `Indicator` equals `N` or `Y`. Is there something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each condition there's a different answer

For

```
coalesce(Indicator, 'N') = 'N'
```

You get

```
coalesce('N', 'N') = 'N' --> 'N' = 'N' --> True
coalesce('Y', 'N') = 'N' --> 'Y' = 'N' --> False
coalesce(Null, 'N') = 'N' --> 'N' = 'N' --> True
```

and for

```
coalesce(Indicator, 'N') = 'Y'
```

you get

```
coalesce('N', 'N') = 'N' --> 'N' = 'N' --> True
coalesce('Y', 'N') = 'N' --> 'Y' = 'N' --> False
coalesce(Null, 'N') = 'Y' --> 'N' = 'Y' --> False
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic does two things.  Functionally, the first expression is equivalent to:

```
(Indicator = 'N' or Indicator is null)
```

In addition, it also prevents an index from being used on `indicator` (in most databases).

For a binary indicator, the use of the index is typically of minor importance.  In addition, SQL optimizers are pretty bad at using indexes for `or` conditions.  And, they almost never use them when a column is an argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce(Indicator, 'N')` says if `Indicator is null` then take `N` as it's value else the value holded by `Indicator`.

so, if `Indicator is null` then the below condition holds `TRUE`

```
coalesce(Indicator, 'N') = 'N'
```